# Sorting 3 or more values with tiebreakers in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, ranking, usort

I'm ranking a list based on a set of tie-breaking criteria using `usort` in PHP. My problem is that the tiebreakers aren't applied correctly when there are 3 or more ties to break. The function only sorts between 2 entries as it iterates through the array.

When 2 entries have identical `Overall wins`, the function checks `Division wins`; if those are identical, it checks `Head to head`; then `Points` if the tie still is not broken. This works great to break the tie between 2 entries, but with 3 or more ties, the iterative nature of this process is an issue.

Example:

3 entries have identical `Overall wins` and `Division wins`, so we check `Head to head` results.

- Team 1 beat Team 2.
- Team 2 beat Team 3.
- Team 3 beat Team 1.

Therefore, we *should* move on to `Points` because the tie cannot be broken with `Head to head` as each team has one win over the other two teams. But my function doesn't ever make that third check, I guess because Team A and Team C aren't next to each other when `usort()` does it's thing...I'm not sure.

Here is the comparison function I pass into `usort`:

```
function set_division_order($a, $b) {
if ($a['wins'] == $b['wins'] && $a['losses'] == $b['losses']) { //same overall record
    if ($a['div_wins'] == $b['div_wins'] && $a['div_losses'] == $b['div_losses']) { //same division record
        $h2h = get_h2h_result($year, $a['team_id'], $b['team_id']);
        if ($h2h == 0) {    //same head-to-head record
            return ($b['pts'] - $a['pts']);
        }
        else {  //head-to-head winner
            return $h2h;
        }
    }
    else {  //different division record
        return ($b['div_wins'] - $a['div_wins']);
    }
}
else {  //different overall record
    return ($b['wins'] - $a['wins']);
}
}
```

The array getting passed into `usort($array, 'set_division_order')` which is causing problems:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 1
            [wins] => 3
            [losses] => 2
            [ties] => 0
            [div_wins] => 3
            [div_losses] => 2
            [div_ties] => 0
            [pts] => 513.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 2
            [wins] => 3
            [losses] => 2
            [ties] => 0
            [div_wins] => 3
            [div_losses] => 2
            [div_ties] => 0
            [pts] => 504.1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 3
            [wins] => 3
            [losses] => 2
            [ties] => 0
            [div_wins] => 3
            [div_losses] => 2
            [div_ties] => 0
            [pts] => 517.7
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 4
            [wins] => 4
            [losses] => 1
            [ties] => 0
            [div_wins] => 4
            [div_losses] => 1
            [div_ties] => 0
            [pts] => 491.9
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 5
            [wins] => 2
            [losses] => 3
            [ties] => 0
            [div_wins] => 2
            [div_losses] => 3
            [div_ties] => 0
            [pts] => 393.3
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [team_id] => 6
            [wins] => 0
            [losses] => 5
            [ties] => 0
            [div_wins] => 0
            [div_losses] => 5
            [div_ties] => 0
            [pts] => 377.9
        )

)
```

Sorry this was kind of long, but hopefully the problem is pretty evident. Now it's just time for a solution! I've scoured the PHP resources for the various sort functions, with no luck. I can't be the only one trying to break a 3-way tie with PHP. :)

If I can get just the tied teams matching that criteria into a separate array, I could use a function to re-sort the original sorted array against the values of this new sub-array to order the tied teams within the main array.

...And my head just exploded.

Thanks!

Comment: well for one thing, this will never work `$mysqli->error` and for a few reasons.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've had no issues with the SQL.

Comment: it's not the sql I'm talking about, it's the error checking, if and when it does fail you.

Comment: @Fred-ii- OK, well, I'll look into that. But I won't be changing the SQL as it is stable and does not throw errors. So I guess just ignore that for now and focus on the problem at hand? :)

Comment: Should I do another `usort()` within this function when comparing `Head to head` results, perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide a sample input array and replace your db query with an array so that we can reproduce the current behavior? (in other words, please provide a MCVE)

Comment: @PatrickQ I added the array that gets sorted (which has a three-way tie in terms of `wins` and `div_wins`). I removed the SQL to avoid confusion. The SQL is correctly determining the head-to-head results between `$a` and `$b`...the problem is `usort()`'s scope doesn't include the team `$c`.

Comment: Sidenote: performing an SQL query *inside* a comparison function seems like a very bad idea. You should retrieve all the information you need before sorting, as the compare function will often visit the same values for different comparisons.

Comment: The problem is that the head-to-head calculation is not transitive: if by head-to-head comparison team A < team B, and team B < team C, then this does *not* guarantee that a head-to-head comparison between A and C will yield: team A < team C. This is problematic, as a sort operation expects there to be a consistent order.

Comment: @trincot I could try storing all head-to-head values between all teams in an array from a single SQL query outside the comp function, but as written, it never does the same query twice because the teams in the `where` clause are unique pairings each time the function runs.

Comment: @trincot I don't think you understand my issue. It regards sports standings. Three teams could each have one win against the other two in a group, which renders a head-to-head comparison meaningless. That's the whole issue. I need to detect when this occurs, so I can move to a secondary value for setting the order among the 3 teams (in this case: points).

Comment: I am of course speaking of 3 teams that have equal wins and losses, and arrive at the head-to-head comparison. Having said that, your case is still not reproducible as it depends on an unknown query result. Please provide an example where the head-to-head results are provided (where they are relevant)

Comment: I think trincot understands your problem perfectly. The problem actually has nothing to do with the depth of comparisons/tie-breakers and has everything to do with the use of head-to-head, which is not sortable in-and-of itself

Comment: @trincot The relevant query results produce the array I printed in my question above. You can see that `team_id` 1, 2, and 3 all have `wins = 3` and `div_wins = 3`. I need a way to detect that occurrence and sort those 3 by `pts`.

Comment: @PatrickQ I don't know what you mean by head-to-head not being "sortable" in and of itself. If Team 1 and Team 2 both have 3 wins and 3 div_wins, but Team 1 beat Team 2 head to head, you can absolutely sort Team 1 above Team 2. It's when the scenario I've described numerous times here comes into play that head-to-head is rendered moot.

Comment: @praguian, it is perfectly possible that team A, B and C have equal wins and losses, but that A won against B, B won against C and C won against A. Why would you sort any of them before the other? Like I said, a head-to-head comparison is not transitive.

Comment: If a comparison logic is not _always_ sortable, then it is _not sortable_, period.

Comment: @trincot Did you read my entire question? I literally post that exact thing. Can we stop arguing purist semantics and address my actual problem, which is how to detect and then sort entries of 3 or more that have identical `wins` and `div_wins`, and are not resolved by a clear head-to-head comparison. (I then want to compare their point totals, another sortable metric.)

Comment: @PatrickQ If Team A beat Team B and C, and Team B beat Team C, then those teams are sortable (A, B, C) by the layman's definition of the term. I'm not really here to argue theory, sorry.

Comment: Well, I guess you've figured it out then.  I'll keep my theory to myself and keep this as my own exercise.

Comment: @PatrickQ I'm sorry, I didn't want to come off like an asshole. I just feel like maybe you two didn't read my entire post. I'm sorting via the A-B comparison when possible, and when not (like the issue I've described), I'm struggling to detect the occurrence and then do a sort-within-a-sort by a secondary metric. Essentially, after my first sort, I need to detect 3+ way ties and sort _just those entries_ by `points`. Is that a better explanation?

Comment: @trincot will be happy to know that I've stored head-to-head results in an array that is created just once and read in for the comparisons, instead of querying SQL each time. :)

Comment: @praguian Apology accepted. Trust me, I read your post thoroughly and completely understand what you're trying to accomplish and the context of it. It's not your explanation that failed you, it's your insistence that this is something that can be handled by a true sorting algorithm. Consider this set of results: 1>2, 3>4, 2>1, 4>3, 1>3, 2>4, 3>2, 4>1, 1>3, 2>4, 3>2, 4>1. ( > represents "defeats"). Assume total points are in desc order 1-4. What should the final order/ranking be? All teams have 3 wins. Using H2H here is insanity. It simply isn't appropriate.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156495/discussion-between-praguian-and-patrick-q).